# Angular: Followed all steps but modal Bootstrap not working

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am creating an application in Angular but I have noticed that modal is not working correctly.
I installed bootstrap 4.5.3 and included the following code in the style.css file:

*@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";*

When I click on the update button it does not open the corresponding window.

The code below is app.module.ts:

```js
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';  
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';  
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';  
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';  
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';  
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';  
import {DataTablesModule} from 'angular-datatables';  
import { CustomerListComponent } from './customer-list/customer-list.component';  
import { AddCustomerComponent } from './add-customer/add-customer.component';  
  
@NgModule({  
  declarations: [  
    AppComponent,  
    CustomerListComponent,  
    AddCustomerComponent,  
  ],  
  imports: [  
    BrowserModule,  
    AppRoutingModule,  
    FormsModule,  
    ReactiveFormsModule,  
    HttpClientModule,  
    DataTablesModule  
  ],  
  providers: [],  
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]  
})  
export class AppModule { }
```

app-routing.module.ts

```js
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';  
    import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';  
    import { CustomerListComponent } from './customer-list/customer-list.component';  
    import { AddCustomerComponent } from './add-customer/add-customer.component';  
      
    const routes: Routes = [  
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'view-customer', pathMatch: 'full' },  
      { path: 'view-customer', component: CustomerListComponent },  
      { path: 'add-customer', component: AddCustomerComponent },  
    ];  
      
    @NgModule({  
      imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],  
      exports: [RouterModule]  
    })  
    export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

customer-list.component.ts

```js
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';  
    import { CustomerService } from '../customer.service';  
    import { Customer } from '../customer';  
    import { Observable,Subject } from "rxjs";  
      
    import {FormControl,FormGroup,Validators} from '@angular/forms';  
      
    @Component({  
      selector: 'app-customer-list',  
      templateUrl: './customer-list.component.html',  
      styleUrls: ['./customer-list.component.css']  
    })  
    export class CustomerListComponent implements OnInit {  
      
     constructor(private customerservice:CustomerService) { }  
      
      customersArray: any[] = [];  
      dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};  
      dtTrigger: Subject<any>= new Subject();  
      
      customers: Observable<Customer[]>;  
      customer : Customer=new Customer();  
      deleteMessage=false;  
      customerlist:any;  
      isupdated = false;      
       
      
      ngOnInit() {  
        };     
        this.customerservice.getCustomerList().subscribe(data =>{  
        this.customers =data;  
        this.dtTrigger.next();  
        })  
      }  
        
      deleteCustomer(id: number) {  
        .
    .
    .  
      }  
      
      updateCustomer(id: number){  
        this.customerservice.getCustomer(id)  
          .subscribe(  
            data => {  
              this.customerlist=data             
            },  
            error => console.log(error));  
      }  
      
      customerupdateform=new FormGroup({  
        customer_id:new FormControl(),  
        customer_name:new FormControl(),  
        customer_email:new FormControl()  
      });  
      
      updateCust(updcust){  
        this.customer=new Customer();   
       this.customer.customer_id=this.CustomerId.value;  
       this.customer.customer_name=this.CustomerName.value;  
       this.customer.customer_email=this.CustomerEmail.value;   
         
      
       this.customerservice.updateCustomer(this.customer.customer_id,this.customer).subscribe(  
        data => {       
          this.isupdated=true;  
          this.customerservice.getCustomerList().subscribe(data =>{  
            this.customers =data  
            })  
        },  
        error => console.log(error));  
      }  
      
      get CustomerName(){  
        return this.customerupdateform.get('customer_name');  
      }  
      
      get CustomerEmail(){  
        return this.customerupdateform.get('customer_email');  
      }  
               
      get CustomerId(){  
        return this.customerupdateform.get('customer_id');  
      }  
      
      changeisUpdate(){  
        this.isupdated=false;  
      }  
    }
```

customer-list.component.html

```js
    <div class="panel panel-default">  
      <div class="panel-heading">  
          <h1 style="text-align: center">Customers</h1><br>  
          <div class="row" [hidden]="!deleteMessage">  
                 
                    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>  
                    <div class="col-sm-4">  
                            <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible">  
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>  
                                    <strong>Customer Data Deleted</strong>  
                            </div>  
                    </div>  
                    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>  
            </div>             
        </div>  
      
        
      <div class="panel-body">  
          <table  class="table table-hover table-sm" datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions"  
          [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger"  >  
              <thead class="thead-light">  
                  <tr>  
                      <th>Customer Name</th>  
                      <th>Customer Email</th> 
                      <th>Action</th>  
                        
                  </tr>  
              </thead>  
              <tbody>  
                   <tr *ngFor="let customer of customers ">  
                      <td>{{customer.customer_name}}</td>  
                      <td>{{customer.customer_email}}</td>  
                      <td><button (click)="deleteCustomer(customer.customer_id)" class='btn btn-primary'><i class="fa fa-futboll-0">Delete</i></button>   
                        <button (click)="updateCustomer(customer.customer_id)" class='btn btn-info'  
                        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Update</button>  
                      </td>  
                    </tr>   
              </tbody><br>  
          </table>  
      </div>  
    </div>   
      
    <div class="modal" id="myModal">        // HERE 
            <div class="modal-dialog">      // PROBLEM
              <div class="modal-content">   // MODAL
                    <form [formGroup]="customerupdateform" #updcust (ngSubmit)="updateCust(updcust)">  
                <!-- Modal Header -->  
                <div class="modal-header">  
                  <h4 class="modal-title" style="text-align: center">Update Customer</h4>  
                    
                </div>  
                  
                <!-- Modal body -->  
                <div class="modal-body" *ngFor="let customer of customerlist " >  
                    <div [hidden]="isupdated">  
      
                        <input type="hidden" class="form-control"  formControlName="customer_id" [(ngModel)]="customer.customer_id">  
                                <div class="form-group">  
                                    <label for="name">Customer Name</label>  
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control"  formControlName="customer_name" [(ngModel)]="customer.customer_name"  >  
                                </div>  
                          
                                <div class="form-group">  
                                    <label for="name">Customer Email</label>  
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="customer_email" [(ngModel)]="customer.customer_email">  
                                </div>  
                          
                   </div>    
                      <div [hidden]="!isupdated">  
                          <h4>Customer Detail Updated!</h4>  
                      </div>          
                          
                </div>  
                  
                <!-- Modal footer -->  
                <div class="modal-footer" >  
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [hidden]="isupdated">Update</button>  
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="changeisUpdate()">Close</button>  
                </div>  
                  
            </form>  
              </div>  
            </div>  
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can (or should) easily mix the standard Bootstrap library, which is currently based on JQuery, with Angular. Importing the CSS will get you the styles but not the behaviour. There are two Angular Bootstrap libraries though that include all the standard Bootstrap components (and more).

[ng-bootstrap modals](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples)

[ngx-bootstrap modals](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals)

Comment: which one do you suggest me to use?